# Would this quantum algorithm implementation work?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, shors-algorithm, cirq

I am trying to implement the order finding algorithm on Cirq finding the minimal positive $r$ for coprime $x$ and $N$ satisfying the equation $x^r \ = \ 1$(mod$ \ N$). In my case, I have set $x \ = \ 2$ and $N \ = \ 3$, so the algorithm should output $r \ = \ 2$. In order to implement the unitary, I simply observed that if we initialize the input that is being acted upon by the controlled-unitary matrices as a collection of $|1\rangle$ states, the unitary operation for this algorithm, $U|y\rangle \ = \ |2^jy \ $mod($3)\rangle$ acts trivially, in all circumstances, since $|y\rangle \ = \ |11\rangle \ = \ |3\rangle$. I feel as though I am missing a very important point, or maybe am not understanding the algorithm correctly, because when I try to implement the algorithm with no unitary gate (since it is supposedly trivial), the algorithm does not work.

Comment: You need $N$ to be a composite number. $N=3$ is prime, and therefore has no smaller prime factors, so there's nothing that the factoring algorithm can do!

Comment: Circuit constructions for modular arithmetic aren't guaranteed to behave correctly on numbers outside the range [0, N). You have N=3 but are trying to operate on 3, which is not less than 3 and therefore out of range.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What exactly does the $|y\rangle$ input represent within the circuit though? Can it just be any eigenvector of the unitary for the controlled-gate, like the standard phase estimation algorithm?

Comment: In Nielsen and Chuang it says that in order to make this algorithm, $|y\rangle$ should be initialized as $|11...1\rangle$.

Comment: @JackCeroni You might be confused by an ambiguity in the notation. In Figure 5.4 of Nielsen and Chuang, the |1> refers to initializing the register to contain the little-endian representation of the integer 1, not to setting all bits to 1. Only the least significant bit is supposed to be 1.

Comment: @CraigGidney Ohhh that makes sense, thank you! Just one more question, if $|y\rangle$ is equal to $1$, why is it even specified in the unitary action on $|y\rangle$ (why don't we just write $U|y\rangle \ = \ |2^j$mod($3)\rangle$)?

Comment: @JackCeroni I think you can do that. They might just be being thorough by defining for all values instead of one value. Also, if you use an operation that works on all values then you can initialize to almost any random value and it will still work. States of the register that don't work, like integers greater than or equal to N and the superposition with all qubits in the + state, are either rare or hard to make (you don't get them by accident).

Comment: @CraigGidney Would that mean that $|y\rangle$ not always initialized in the $|1\rangle$ state for the order-finding algorithm?

Comment: @JackCeroni People usually just use $|1\rangle$ because it's simplest, but there are papers that point out you don't have to e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0601097

Comment: @CraigGidney Great, thank you for all your help!